# How can I pass string type in class in numba jitclass python?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

while I added this before my class but I noticed that I passed a string to my class when I neglected to declare it for `jitclass` can't work and when i trying using string to be the same type can't use it.

```
spec = [
    ('filename', str),
    ('rows', int32),
    ('cls', int32),
    ('L', int32),
    ('H', int32),
    ('checking', int32[:]),
    ('enum_file', int32[:]),
    ('step', int32),
    ('slices', int32),
]
```

@jitclass(spec)

TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got `<class 'str'>`
..........................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It's a little ugly, but might be a good enough workaround:

```
import numba as nb

spec = [
    ('filename', nb.uint8[:]),
    ('rows', nb.int32),
    ('cls', nb.int32),
    ('L', nb.int32),
    ('H', nb.int32),
    ('checking', nb.int32[:]),
    ('enum_file', nb.int32[:]),
    ('step', nb.int32),
    ('slices', nb.int32),
]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class A:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.filename = fname
```

and then:

```
a = A(np.frombuffer(b'abcdef', dtype='uint8'))
print(a.filename.tostring())
```

You won't be able to use `tostring()` in a `nopython` jitted function, but if you're just using it outside of numba, it works.